# What is the correct way of maintaining indices for Sunspot Solr?

Tags: solr, indexing, mongoid, sunspot

I am confused about the Solr indexing mechanism. Perhaps someone can shed some light on it.

So, we have 2 rake commands: `rake sunspot:solr:index` and `rake sunspot:solr:reindex`

Here's what my `index` task looks like (I overrode it for Mongoid):

```
namespace :sunspot do
  namespace :solr do 
    desc "indexes searchable models"
    task :index => :environment do
      [Model1, Model2].each do |model|
        Sunspot.index!(model.all)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As far as I understand, my definition of `index` is effectively reindexing the collections each time I run it.

Am I right?
Does it overwrite the previous index or do I have to use `reindex` to drop the old and create the new indices?

I am using gems `sunspot v2.0.0`, `sunspot_mongo v1.0.1`, `sunspot_solr v2.0.0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reindex task just calls `solr_reindex` on each of the models, and source for that method is below (taken from github).

```
   # Completely rebuild the index for this class. First removes all 
   # instances from the index, then loads records and indexes them.
   #   
   # See #index for information on options, etc.
   #   
   def solr_reindex(options = {}) 
     solr_remove_all_from_index
     solr_index(options)
   end
```

If you look at the source to `solr_index`, the comments say that the method wil "Add/update all existing records in the Solr index."

So to answer your question, the the `reindex` task is essentially the same as the `index` task, except that the `reindex` task will first drop the existing index.  If you have items in your index that you know shouldn't be there, you should call `reindex`.  If you know that you only are adding or updating items in the index, you can just call `index` and not suffer the performance hit of dropping the index and then rebuilding it from scratch.